# Why running function Array(){} in nodejs REPL will destroy nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some minutes ago I came up with an idea of re-defining the built-in `Array` constructor in user's script scope, like:

```
function Array () {}
```

In Chrome Dev Tools it overrides the built-in `Array` of the global scope (of all <script>) but leaves Chrome's js' scope unmodified (which means that the js codes of Chrome itself work correctly), as I have expected.

However, when I performed a test in Node.js, I got lots of this (to be more specific, one per tick):

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js:488:13)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:478:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

It kept outputting and Node.js had no response to my input so I have to kill it.
I performed further tests such as `function Object () {}` and `function Number () {}`, both resulted in Node.js' force exit:

```
internal/util/inspect.js:292
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'constructor');
                          ^

TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor is not a function
    at getConstructorName (internal/util/inspect.js:292:31)
    at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:477:23)
    ... (other stacks)
    at Domain._errorHandler (domain.js:224:23)
    at Object.setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback (domain.js:140:29)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:490:31)
```

and

```
internal/async_hooks.js:121
  if (!Number.isSafeInteger(asyncId) || asyncId < -1) {
              ^

TypeError: Number.isSafeInteger is not a function
    at validateAsyncId (internal/async_hooks.js:121:15)
    at emitInitScript (internal/async_hooks.js:317:3)
    ...
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:725:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:410:12)
```

(Executing `function String () {}` in Node.js REPL is okay at first, but further typing and moving the cursor causes it to quit)

I knew that in Node.js' script file running mode, the content will be wrapped with `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {` and thus the modification in current scope won't interfere the Node.js' inner scripts' scope.

So why modifying `Object` and `Array`, etc. will cause Node.js REPL to quit unexpectedly? It doesn't make sense to me...

> I'm using Node.js 10.12.0 on macOS with nvm as version manager.
>
> Also tested on Node.js 8.9.4 and got similar results.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: The errors for the `Object` and `Number` examples are obvious (the error will be thrown in chrome too). As for the `Array` example, you'll have to provide more context, what code did throw the error?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I can reproduce it, just run Node, type in `function Array () {}` and press enter

Comment: Yeah that's weird. But I guess the nodejs REPL is way different than chrome's console.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir just simply run `function Array () {}` will throw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devoted several hours searching through the Internet...

And I found [this](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1341) in `nodejs/help` repo:

> Creating a variable using `var` in the global scope creates (overrides) property of the global object with the same name. Therefore `var Date = 3` is equivalent to `global.Date = 3`, but `Date` is used by Node.js REPL script.
>
> The only way to safely execute scripts in REPL is to run them in a separate realm, which Node.js doesn't currently do. Otherwise, user scripts may override any of the useful global properties.
>
> It is not hard to break REPL. For example, `String.prototype.replace = null` also terminates the process.

So, that seems related to my problem and after a careful investigation of the Node.js source code, I found out that the REPL codes do not have a separate scope and thus it can be easily destroyed by overwriting built-in objects. Node.js' js codes will behave incorrectly due to the modification of those objects and result in `TypeError`s.